# Web Scraping with Python - blank return

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape reviews from TrustPilot, but the code always return with blank sheets and the headers/categories I specified. Could someone help me with this?

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import pandas as pd
driver= webdriver.Chrome()
names=[] #List to store name of the product
headers=[] #List to store price of the product
bodies=[]
ratings=[] #List to store rating of the product
dates=[]
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page=2")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True, attrs={'class':'reviews-container'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'consumer-information_name'})
    header=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'review-content_title'})
    body=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'review-content_text'})
    rating=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'star-rating star-rating--medium'})
    date=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'review-date--tooltip-target'})
    names.append(name.text)
    headers.append(header.text)
    bodies.append(body.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text)
    dates.append(date.text)

print ('webpage, no errors')

df = pd.DataFrame({'User Name':names,'Header':headers,'Body':bodies,'Rating':ratings,'Date':dates})
df.to_csv('reviews02.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

print ('csv made')```
````

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `soup.findAll('a', href=True, attrs={'class':'reviews-container'})` is not finding any results, so there are 0 iterations in the loop. Make sure you are using the correct tags and class names. Also you don't need to use a loop because BeautifulSoup has a `find_all` method. I used the requests module to open the web page, though it shouldn't make a difference.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
req = requests.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page=2")
content = req.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
names = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'consumer-information__name'})
headers = soup.find_all('h2', attrs={'class':'review-content__title'})
bodies = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'})
ratings = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'star-rating star-rating--medium'})
dates = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'review-content-header__dates'})
```

And now each list has 20 entries.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I would like to ask where should I add your code to mine? Or which lines do I replace with your code? Sorry I don't really have any prior knowledge on python.

Comment: Also is it possible to loop the code such that it collects data from every pages of the review comments, in case there are multiple pages?

Comment: @SaraJitkresorn My code replaces everything until you create the data frame. To get all the reviews you can write a loop to iterate though the result pages, which involves updating the URL to the next page number.